# rails - error loading "new" page made with ruby on rails scaffolding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, scaffolding

I have a simple rails app with devise set up and a profile model that I created. I have set up my associations and everything seems fine, however when I try to access the new_profile_path with a new user account, I get the following Error:

NoMethodError in ProfilesController#new
undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #17):
15
16
17
18
19
20

def new
    @profile = current_user.profile.build
    respond_with(@profile)
  end

The problem seems to be in my profiles controller, however I cant seem to figure out the issue. This is the entire code for my profiles controller:-

```html
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
@profiles = Profile.all
respond_with(@profiles)
  end

  def show
respond_with(@profile)
  end

  def new
@profile = current_user.build_profile
respond_with(@profile)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
@profile = current_user.build_profile(profile_params)
@profile.save
respond_with(@profile)
  end

  def update
@profile.update(profile_params)
respond_with(@profile)
  end

  def destroy
@profile.destroy
respond_with(@profile)
  end

  private
def set_profile
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end

def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:name, :civil, :email, :level, :employment_date, :mobile, :folder, :title, :internal, :nationality, :vacation, :work_email, :experience)
end
end
```

My html link:-

```
<nav>
    <ul>
         <li><%= link_to root_path do %>
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>Main
            <% end %>
        </li>
        <% if !current_user.profile.blank? %>
          <li><%= link_to profile_path(current_user.profile.id) do %>
             <i class="fa fa-user"></i>Employee Profile<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
          <% end %>
          <% else %>
                <li><%= link_to new_profile_path do %><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>Create Profile</li>
                <% end %>
          <% end %>
                <ul>
                    <li><%= link_to "Tasks / Activities", tasks_path %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Vacations", vacations_path %></li>
                </ul>
         </li>
         <li><%= link_to projects_path do %>
                <i class="fa fa-building-o"></i>Projects<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
                <% end %>
            <ul>
                <li><%= link_to active_path do %>Active Projects<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                    <% end %>
                    <ul>
                        <li><%= link_to "Preliminary Stage", presignature_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "Design Stage", develop_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "Tendered Stage", proposed_path %></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><%= link_to "Archive", archive_path %></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
       <li><%= link_to project_docs_path do %>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>Project Documents<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
        <% end %>
            <ul>
                <li><%= link_to "Preliminary Stage", presignature2_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to development2_path do %>Design Stage<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                    <% end %>
                    <ul>
                        <li><%= link_to "Phase 1", phase1_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "Phase 2", phase2_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "Phase 3", phase3_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "Phase 4", phase4_path %></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><%= link_to "Tendered Projects", proposed2_path %></li>
            </ul>
       </li>
       <li><%= link_to search_path do %>
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search
        <% end %>
       </li>
       <li><%= link_to reports_path do %>
        <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>Reports
        <% end %>
       </li>
       <li><%= link_to feedback_path do %>
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>Feedback
        <% end %>
       </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My Profile model:

```html
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end
```

My User model:-

```html
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :profile
end
```

I hope the issue is clear enough. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:-

after updating the profile controller code to the one above, I am now receiving a new error:

ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Profiles#new

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Extracted source (around line #8):
5
6
7
8
9
10
11

```
            <% end %>
        </li>
        <% if !current_user.profile.blank? %>
         <li><%= link_to profile_path(current_user.profile) do %>
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>Employee Profile<i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
     <% end %>
            <% else %>
```

its says there is a problem with this line:

<%= link_to profile_path(current_user.profile) do %>

Comment: please post your user and profile model

Comment: I have just updated the the question.

Comment: try this `<%= link_to profile_path(current_user.profile.id) do %>`

Comment: tried it, still get the same error message.

Comment: Please post the whole view file.

Comment: ok I just updated the question again with the full view file.

Comment: Please reformat the code properly

Comment: Ok the formatting is fixed. sorry it was an issue as I copied the code incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_user` does not yet have a `profile`, so you can't call `build` on it.  What I think you want is:

```
@profile = current_user.build_profile
```

This is an auto-generated method that rails provides for you.
The [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) is a little dense, but here it is.
[This might be a little more readable](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: I tried your code, however I am now receiving a new error. I have updated my question with the new code plus more details about the error and my html code for the links, please check it if you dont mind. thanks :)

Comment: That's because `build` does not save the record to the database.  So there's no ID, so you can't link to it.  Perhaps what you wanted all along was `create`, which does save to the database.  Be aware the `create` requires that you pass enough params for it to pass your validations.  Seems you might not in this case.  I see that you create a profile when you get back from `new`, in your `#create` method, which makes more sense.  I think the real problem is that your are trying to do too much in your `new` view - not enough stuff has been created yet.

Comment: I haven't delved deep enough into Resources and their specific functions as im quite new to rails (and coding in general), so I guess il take a step back and figure out how it works. Do you know any particularly helpful resources to start with? Thanks for the help by the way! :)

Comment: The Guides I posted in my answer are definitely the best resource to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
def new 
  @profile = Profile.new 
  respond_with(@profile) 
end
```

You can always call the current_user in the create method.

Comment: The problem with that is it won't get linked to the current user.

Comment: Yes that is indeed the case.